Image generation/editing AI which is good at prompts related to glyphs/text
Is there anything that can process prompts like "Generate a dragon with body shaped like letter D" or "Change that dragon's body shape from letter S to letter D"?
I tried Bing first - it was ok, but didn't manage to generate exactly what I need with bunch of attempts.
Then I tried Midjourney - despite requiring payment, it was actually worse and didn't understand what e.g. letter "D" is at all. No matter if I tried they selective mode or even showing some mocks.
Lastly I tried Stable Diffusion locally and that either required some serious, long training or was far behind the most popular competitors.
Not sure about other ones. Does anone have experience with such prompts?

Gemini generated many images where the D was not readable, but also some where it is very readable and still part of the dragon's body:


Disclaimer: Made by my company.

Thanks. I don't think it's available for me as of now unfortunately, unless I'm missing something. I'm from EU. Prompt like "generate image" doesn't work and says it's something that can't be done now.
